# Как вернуть данные из приложения на ASP NET Core 3.1 в JSON формате?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Всем привет, вопрос в следующем, есть приложение на ASP NET Core 3.1, которая возврощает некотрую информацию из БД, в данный момент это просто IEnumerable и когда в приложении отправляется HTTP запрос, то на экран вывводится набор чисел (опять-же информация из БД) а как можно получить резултат запроса в JSON формате?

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, тип проекта (MVC / Web Api)

Answer (score 0):

Ну для [API контроллеров](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42360139/5752652) точно сработает такой вариант:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Get()
{
    return Json(/* my variable */);
}
```

но вроде и [в обычном контроллере](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/5.4.php) сработает.